# Need help on using COUNT and SUM together in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have got 2 tables: Institute & Course

```
Institute
---------
i_id       i_name      i_city
------     --------    --------
1          Name 1      London
2          Name 2      Manchester
3          Name 3      London

Course
-------
c_id       i_id        stream
------     -------     --------
1          1           Engineering
2          1           Engineering
3          2           Engineering
4          3           Engineering
```

Now I am trying to achieve 3 things:

a) Number of Institutes per city offering Engineering courses.
b) Total (distinct) Number of Institutes offering Engineering courses.

I started writing below query to achieve this:

```
SELECT institute.i_city, 
COUNT( DISTINCT institute.i_id ) AS institute_count_per_city
FROM institute, course
WHERE institute.i_id = course.i_id
AND course.stream =  'Engineering'
GROUP BY institute.i_city
```

I got below result:

```
i_city      institute_count_per_city
-------     -------------------------
London      2
Manchester  1
```

Now I have achieved the count of institutes per city.

I can't figure how can I get the total number of institutes in same query which in the above example will be 3 (2+1)

I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`ROLLUP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html):

```
SELECT institute.i_city, 
COUNT( DISTINCT institute.i_id ) AS institute_count_per_city
FROM institute, course
WHERE institute.i_id = course.i_id
AND course.stream =  'Engineering'
GROUP BY institute.i_city WITH ROLLUP
```

It will add additional row with `SUM` of your aggregated values.

***Update***

*`GrandTotal`* version:

```
SELECT IFNULL(institute.i_city, 'GrandTotal'), 
COUNT( DISTINCT institute.i_id ) AS institute_count_per_city
FROM institute, course
WHERE institute.i_id = course.i_id
AND course.stream =  'Engineering'
GROUP BY institute.i_city WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: +1 This would give you an additional row with city `null` and the total count of institutes that offer an engineering ocurse.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is perfect! Can I replace null with something else like GrandTotal?

Comment: Thanks mate. That's what I wanted. It works like charm now!! Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @RishabGarg You're welcome! And because you're new here: you should read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/208082). That's how StackOverflow works :)

Answer (score 1):

Would a union query help?

```
 your existing query
 union
 select 'total' I_city, count(*) institute_count_per_city
 FROM institute, course
 WHERE institute.i_id = course.i_id
 AND course.stream =  'Engineering'
 GROUP BY 'total'
```